# Mongodb Finding average of depends on the value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

This is my collection which has the information of a list of units of course and field to denote if a unit is already read or not.

```
{
    "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
    "units": [
        {
            "unit": "612f5608dc3813268a766417",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5608dc38133ee6766411",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "61322aa16c985ae927308a82",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f560cdc38137394766440",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5614dc38139a927664b2",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5621dc381387d976653f",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "612f5622dc381383dd766545",
    "units": [
        {
            "unit": "612f5625dc3813e311766560",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5625dc381386bb76655a",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5626dc38132a2d766566",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5628dc3813a36d7665bd",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5626dc3813af32766574",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
    ]
},
```

I want output as below. Just need to find the average depends on the `alreadyRead` field and put it in `avgCompleted`. Is there any way to do this?

```
{
    "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
    "units": [
        {
            "unit": "612f5608dc3813268a766417",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5608dc38133ee6766411",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "61322aa16c985ae927308a82",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f560cdc38137394766440",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5614dc38139a927664b2",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5621dc381387d976653f",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        }
    ],
    "avgCompleted": 50
},
{
    "_id": "612f5622dc381383dd766545",
    "units": [
        {
            "unit": "612f5625dc3813e311766560",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5625dc381386bb76655a",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5626dc38132a2d766566",
            "alreadyRead": 1
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5628dc3813a36d7665bd",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
        {
            "unit": "612f5626dc3813af32766574",
            "alreadyRead": 0
        },
    ],
    "avgCompleted": 60
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) and multiply by 100 to get the value you want.

- Using `$set` you create the field `avgCompleted` where the value is `100 * $avg`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "avgCompleted": {
        "$multiply": [
          100,
          {
            "$avg": "$units.alreadyRead"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mb-cR53Mdkq)